# In regard to "note"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can I say "I will note your requirements" to mean that I will mention your requirements in an Email?

Is there any way to put it?

Comment: how about 'I will summarize/ add your requirements' ?

Comment: It probably depends on the context. The basic meaning of this sentence is simply that you'll keep the requirements in mind, not that you'll do anything more active with them.